# XGBoost tutorial - problem with understanding transformation

Tags: boosting

I'm following tutorial in xgboost docs: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model.html

I'm stuck on this step:
[image]

I don't understand how the first term (loss) was transformed, they seem to not be equal (sympy says so too). I'm thinking there may be some magic with constant term involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that you're minimizing $obj^{(t)}$ with respect to the function $f_t$. The $\sum(y_i - \hat{y_i}^{(t - 1)})^2$ term, which appears to be missing from the second line, went into the constant, because its derivative with respect to $f_t$ is always going to be zero.